# Relevant C++ programming books for Real time applications (Games, Simulators and the likes)

Tags: c++, scientific-computing

**LATER EDIT:**
*Please mention not only game programming books, but also more scientific/simulation oriented books written for C++ programmers. As mentioned in one comment, this is why I chose to post the question on a more general SO site. Thank you all!*

**please**, *no specialized books presenting algorithms and techniques with C++ snippets - aka any Gems series, etc. Please expand on Scott Meyer's Effective C++ with similar, more complete or better book examples, or take into account that I mentioned a book for scientists and engineers.*

Although similar questions have been asked, what I strictly need to know as a collection of opinions is which books are relevant for a person that has intermediate C++ skills, but wants to learn tips, tricks, good practices and polish up on their coding style to develop an edge in writing efficient number crunching applications (these applications should be dedicated to perform mathematical computations with customized structures, rendering/graphics and communicate with the user).

What I would like to see in an answer is a mention of a truly relevant fundamental C++ book, then 2 to 3 books (series also accepted - e.g. Scott Meyers' Effective C++) focused on intermediate to advanced programming tips, one of these 2-3 dealing exactly with tips and tricks for efficient computations within numerical scenarios/simulation/graphics/etc. I think there was a book called C++ for Scientists and Engineers, I'm not sure though how well this is rated as I haven't finished reading it :(. Perhaps a book that illustrates what design patterns are relevant for scientists/engineers/game programmers?

Thank you all. (hope this will help programmers that aren't keen on learning how to manipulate data just for the sake of making a living out of programming, as most average programmers tend to do nowadays).

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question. All answers are talking solely about game development

Comment: In the future, you may want to look into asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . While there are game development tags here, that entire website is dedicated to game development questions.

Comment: @josephthomas Sure, I considered asking the question there, but I guess I had to make the statement a bit clearer: Books for Scientific Applications, Real-time simulations with heavy use of Mathematics, Physics and Graphics. That's why I mentioned C++ for Scientists and Engineers [link](http://www.amazon.com/Scientific-Engineering-Introduction-Advanced-Techniques/dp/0201533936). Game programming books are also good, but most of them elude the problem of designing good number crunching algorithms along with corresponding data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you venture into a specialization, be sure you have a solid grasp of C++. With that being said, here are some books I would personally recommend.

[Game Engine Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814135) has become the book you want to read for game development. Having read the book from front to cover, I can say the author does a wonderful job of presenting a large amount of material.

[Game Engine Gems 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763778885) and [Game Engine Gems 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568814372) present excellent topics that for game development also.

If you are new to graphics programming, and you are on Windows, you may appreciate [Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936420228). I have read the previous two books in the "series" by Frank Luna and while I am still working on finishing this one, in my opinion they present the most correct material.

Comment: Luna is great. Good to see his new DX11 book is finally back in stock. Also check out [Practical Rendering and Computation with Direct3D 11](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Rendering-Computation-Direct3D-11/dp/1568817207/) which has some great examples.

Comment: +1 for your mentions. Game Engine Gems do not make the topic of my question because they're focused on actual algorithms and little to none on how one should code (good practices!) such algorithms. They're similar to GPU Gems, Shader X and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

I found [C++ For Game Programmers (2nd Ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584504528) to be a good intermediate-level C++ primer focused on performance-oriented C++.

[Video Game Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598634356) provides good coverage on C++ optimization (at high and low level), profiling tools, and general approaches to optimization (both CPU and GPU).

Answer (score 1):

If number crunching in is your thing, you absolutely need to own one of the [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) books (in this case, [Numerical Recipes in C++](http://www.nr.com/cpp-blurb.html) is the obvious one).  The supporting text elevates these books way above being mere "code fragment" collections.